# Date - 1 minute in hive

Tags: sql, hive

need help in below problem:
I am using Hive UI, I have to minus 1 minute from date-time (string)

(2019-03-29 00:00 - 1 min)

below is not working:

```
         DATEADD(minute,-1, cast(first_value(colt.start_date) over
                                   (partition by table.period,table.model_name
                                     order by table.start_date desc
                                     rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                                   ) as timestamp
                                 )
                )
```

or

date_add(FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP
                         (first_value(table.start_date)over
                           (partition by
                           table.ytd_glperiod,table.model_name
                           order by table.start_date desc
                           rows between unbounded preceding and current row
                           ),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                         )
                      ),-1
         )

Answer (score 0):

To subtract a minute from a value in Hive, use:

```
<col> - interval '1' minute
```

This works for more complex expressions as well.

Comment: Thanks but its Hive UI and this syntax is not supporting

Comment: @AnkitSoni . . . Hive supports intervals and interval arithmetic.  The documentation is a little scattered on the subject, but  here is a reference:  http://dwgeek.com/hive-interval-data-types-and-conversion-examples.html/.